# CPAN.pm change .gz path

Tags: perl, cpan

I am trying to change the `CPAN.pm` to include the destination of `.gz` file in the `CPAN.pm` but as I don't have the "sudo" rights hence its denying my access.

My question is how to uninstall the CPAN if it's possible and install again.

Is there any other solution for such cases.

Following command doesn't work:

```
cpan o conf init
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use user local configuration in `~/.cpan/CPAN/MyConfig.pm`, put this inside :

```
$CPAN::Config = {
  'gzip' => q[/usr/bin/gzip]
};

1;
```

Adapt the `gzip` path if needed.

Comment: Execute Permission Denied.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. `~/.cpan/CPAN/MyConfig.pm` may be owned by your user

Comment: if it helps. cpan was installed by me and the "which cpan" gave me the following path "/usr/bin/cpan". I installed it some time ago and did a mistake in providing the directory path for .gz

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean that you want to change where CPAN.pm stores archive files after it downloads them? There's a setting called `keep_sources_where`:

```
% cpan
cpan[1]> o conf keep_source_where
    keep_source_where  [/Users/brian/.cpan/sources]
Type 'o conf' to view all configuration items


cpan[2]> o conf keep_source_where /some/other/dir
    keep_source_where  [/some/other/dir]
Please use 'o conf commit' to make the config permanent!
```

There are several other setting that you can look at and set. They are all listed in the [CPAN](http://www.metacpan.org/module/CPAN) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is

```
perl -MCPAN -e shell

o conf gzip /usr/bin/gzip
o conf commit
```

Done..... 
Same for everything . No need to reinstall CPAN if you want only to change some configuration.